# asp.net 4 dropdownlist findByText not working for dynamic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist, whose datasource is from SQL server.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="State" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="STATE_NAME" DataValueField="STATE_FIPS">
</asp:DropDownList>
                                   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                                       SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [STATE_NAME], [STATE_FIPS] FROM [county] order by [STATE_NAME]">
                                   </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to prepopulate the value in the list. i use `DropDownList.SelectedIndex = DropDownList.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList.Items.FindByValue(YourValueHere))`. but it's not working. it gives me a null from `DropDownList.Items.FindByValue(YourValueHere)`.

The same code works fine if i use static listitem, like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>item1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>item2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>item3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>item4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about directly using the `SelectedValue` property of the dropdown:  `DropDownList.SelectedValue = YourValueHere;` ?

**Edit:** I got your problem, you have to Select `DropDownList Class` instead of the `id of your dropdownlist control`. The code below code is working, I tested it.

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue("item3"));
```

Comment: yes. the code `ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue("item3"));` works for the static listitems, but not dynamic one.

Comment: i think so too. but dunno why it doesn't work here. i'm using asp.net 4.0

Comment: I would suggest you to use SelectedValue Property instead.

Comment: yes. i'm using it right now. it works like a charm. thx man! :D

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. However in my case the dropdownlist was databound two times. 1 by myself and 1 via the parent control. After the second databound the selected index was reset.

So check if the control is databound twice.

You can also implement the selection of the item in de 
void yourdropdown_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) method.
If you breakpoint this method you'll notice the databind is done twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, which works for static and dynamic values:

```c#
ddl.FindItemByText("YourText").Selected = true;
```